# Not able to connect to Azure Virtual Machine using Remote Desktop after my VM got restarted

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, rdp, azure-virtual-machine, remote-login

Today, my azure subscription credit has expired and my VM got shutdown automatically. I have added my credit and activated my account and restarted my virtual machine. But now, I am not able to remote login to my VM using Remote desktop like before. 
I have checked the endpoints for "Remote Desktop (TCP, 3389, 3389)" and it exist. And check the VM status and it is Running. 
But when i tried to login using Remote Desktop it says "Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons: 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled 2) The remote computer is turned off 3) The remote computer is not available on the network"

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance
Sundar

Comment: Go to dashboard of the VM and download Connect and try to connect it. It will helps you because when the VM is shutdown it will change your public IP so don't try with ip to connect the remote server.

Comment: I used the correct public IP address taken from the dashboard. The same scenario happened earlier when i tried to sysprep the VM my access to the Remote Desktop was cut off. Similar to the issue in the link below https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2642e63-9e9a-4428-a13a-3fca5318c5ce/cannot-rdp-vm-after-sysprep?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows .  The only work around was to discard that VM and create a new one.  What i am facing is the similar issue of not able to login to VM using RDP.  This time i didn't do sysprep, the machine was shutdown due to low credit limit.

Answer (score 2):

Check machine IP address. Becuase IP usually changes after shutdown.

Comment: I used the correct public IP address taken from the dashboard. The same scenario happened earlier when i tried to sysprep the VM my access to the Remote Desktop was cut off. Similar to the issue in the link below https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2642e63-9e9a-4428-a13a-3fca5318c5ce/cannot-rdp-vm-after-sysprep?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows .  The only work around was to discard that VM and create a new one.  What i am facing is the similar issue of not able to login to VM using RDP.  This time i didn't do sysprep, the machine was shutdown due to low credit limit.

Comment: I've run into similar problem.. Creating a new VM doesn't seem to be solution. Did u guys manage to find a solution for it.